# Which family of function does a $\frac{n}{\log(n)}$ function belong?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am not a mathematics wizard. Like a $n \log(n)$ function belongs to quasilinear family of functions, what is the function family that $\frac n {\log(n)}$ function belongs to?

Comment: no idea what you are talking about. What is the definition of a quasilinear function?

Comment: maybe this is better: who says $n \log n$ is quasilinear?

Comment: @WillJagy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Quasilinear_time

Comment: I see. You would probably just call it sublinear.

Comment: @WillJagy a couple of people 'guessed' it as sublinear function. Can you confirm or explain ?

Comment: It is a matter of usage, just a name. A sublinear function of, say, positive integers, is some $f(n)$ such that the limit of $f(n)/n$ as $n$ goes to infinity is $0.$ That is the case here, as $(n / \log n)/ n = 1 /  \log n.$  There are various rigorous topics that talk about growth rates of functions, one of these is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_field

Comment: Just for flavor, note that your function is eventually much smaller than $n$ itself. On the other hand, it is eventually much larger than $\sqrt n.$ There are arbitrarily fine distinctions possible in growth. Sublinear is the simplest term that came to mind. Note that the computer science use of the term quasilinear is simply incorrect in mathematics terms. That is, your usage may be standard in computer science books, or may become standard over time. The main use of the word quasilinear in mathematics is as a description of some partial differential equations.